# vscode autopep8 don't run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I just ran autopep8 in vscode, system reports two errors:

> Error: Command failed: autopep8 c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python\从入门到实践\have a try\5-10.py usage: autopep8 [-h] [--version] [-v] [-d] [-i] [--global-config filename] [--ignore-local-config] [-r] [-j n] [-p n] [-a] [--experimental] [--exclude globs] [--list-fixes] [--ignore errors] [--select errors] [--max-line-length n] [--line-range line line] [--hang-closing] [--exit-code] [files [files ...]] autopep8: error: autopep8 only takes one filename as argument unless the "--in-place" or "--diff" args are used

and

> usage: autopep8 [-h] [--version] [-v] [-d] [-i] [--global-config filename] [--ignore-local-config] [-r] [-j n] [-p n] [-a] [--experimental] [--exclude globs] [--list-fixes] [--ignore errors] [--select errors] [--max-line-length n] [--line-range line line] [--hang-closing] [--exit-code] [files [files ...]] autopep8: error: autopep8 only takes one filename as argument unless the "--in-place" or "--diff" args are used

Anyone knows why? I try my best but also don't know what I should do.

I am using:

> Extension:Python-autopep8
>
> vscode:1.33.1

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, you can direct your directory to where your file is. Then use this command:

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>
```

For example:

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive main.py
```

Normally, when you use a terminal in VScode. Your directory is present as to where it should be already. Unless your file is in a sub-folder.

Everything you need can be found at https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/

Comment: this ignores the settings made in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Your file path contains a space in it "have a try". This is interpreted as multiple file names.

To resolve this, I just ensured that the file path does not contain any spaces.